# JQuery and Facebook API function priority/precedence

Tags: jquery, facebook

I would like to logout a user from my website and FB.

First preventDefault (prevent form submit) then getLoginStatus (FB access token required) then call FB.logout, and finally submit the logout form on my page.

```
$("logout-button").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response && !responce.error) {
            if (response.status === "connected") {
                FB.logout();
            }
        }
    });
    $("logout-form").submit();
});
```

The problem is that the submit takes precedence and the FB.logout() is never called.

Any suggestion as to how to make this script always execute FB.getLoginStatus first, wait for function exe and finally call submit?

Answer (score 1):

FB.getLoginStatus should get used on page load, so you can just store the user ID in a variable - to check if the user is logged in:

```
var userID;
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        userID = response.authResponse.userID;
    }
});
```

....and then:

```
$("logout-button").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (userID) {
        FB.logout();
    }
    $("logout-form").submit();
});
```

Just my untested idea, but it should work. You should always call FB.logout and FB.login on user interaction - right now you are calling it in the asynchronous callback function of FB.getLoginStatus.

Comment: The problem is not the accessToken at all. Let's say we forget about the access token and we have this -> $("logout-button").click(function (event) {event.preventDefault(); FB.logout(); $("logout-form").submit();}); The problem is that submit comes first and FB.logout() second. As my question title suggests - function priority.

Comment: i did not mention the accessToken at all, you don´t need to worry about the token while using the js sdk (in most cases).

Comment: i´ve added some more information to my answer. i know exactly what you are trying to do, no worries :)

Comment: I added the following arg to the FB.init - status: true. This will check the FB user status on each page load. Then for the logout event -> if (FB.getUserID()) {FB.logout();)} $("#account-form").submit(); Without the status: true id didn't work. The disadvantage here is that this state arg will slow down the performance. In any case I found your suggestions helpful. A vote for Pedro!

Comment: fb.init does not have that status parameter...i think it only works with fb.getLoginStatus. but thanx, you make pedro happy :)

Comment: yeah: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus > "Roundtrips to Facebook's servers"

Comment: btw, you should not use stuff that is not documented, there is no FB.getUserID - you should use getLoginStatus right after FB.init to check for the user and store the id for later.